# Datatables column sorting/ordering on table columns nested within another table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to add alphanumeric sorting/ordering to the columns of ***the child*** datatables.

**EDIT** I've updated the HTML portion after fixing some formatting issues.
I am now getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')
```

I've been researching different causes of this error and often it seems it's caused by a mismatch of column headers and columns. If my tables are malformed I can't tell (I'm also somewhat novice with frontend/JS code)

table of tables

```
<table class="Dashboard dataTable no-footer" id="scrollTable" role="grid">

        <caption>Cart Status</caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Filling</th>
            <th>Full</th>
            <th>In Use</th>
            <th>Empty</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">
                <table id="fillingTable" class="Data dataTable no-footer">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sort1</th>
                        <th>Sort2</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a style="color: red;" href="#" onclick="getConfirmation('11518','W113PC2')">W113PC2</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table id="fullTable" class="Data">
                    <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sort1</th>
                    <th>Sort2</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span style="color: red; font-weight: bold; ">W321DC1</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">W543DC1</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">W678DC1</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">W405PC1</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">W113DC1</span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">W405PC5</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
  ... 2 tables excluded
</table>
```

javascript

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
           $('table.Dashboard').DataTable({
                paging: false,
                searching: false,
                info: false,
           });

            $('#fillingTable').DataTable({
                paging: false,
                searching: false,
                info: false
            });
            $('#fillingTable tr:last').remove();

            $('#fullTable').DataTable({
                paging: false,
                searching: false,
                info: false
            });
            $('#fullTable tr:last').remove();

            $('#inUseTable').DataTable({
                paging: false,
                searching: false,
                info: false
            });
            $('#inUseTable tr:last').remove();

            $('#emptyTable').DataTable({
                paging: false,
                searching: false,
                info: false
            });
            $('#emptyTable tr:last').remove();

        });
```

Comment: I can see a few problems - too many to suggest a solution, (1) The selector `$('table.Dashboard')` doesn't select anything except the outer table. (2) The option `orderData` does not have that syntax. Did you mean just `order`? (3) The HTML in the question is malformed - for example, you have `<tr>` inmediately followed by `<tr>`, so you need to validate all the HTML for correctness.

Comment: (4) The two nested tables do not conform to what DataTables needs - for example, they have no `<thead>`, so there is nowhere to put column headings (needed for sorting). There may be more issues hiding behind these. Suggestion: You can [edit] your question to provide a cleaner [mre] - one which illustrates the specific problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @andrewJames I did try selecting each table individually and then used `order: []` on them which also didn't work - like you said because of the lack of headers on the child tables. I tried moving the headers into each table which also didn't work (and ruined the formatting). The columns for each table are not malformed, 2 values per row is a requirement (and created with struts) which could also be adding an additional wrinkle.

Comment: OK - but I cannot tell what it is you are trying to do. Are you trying to order the parent table rows based on some data inside the child tables in the columns of the parent table? Or are you trying to order the data inside each child table in a self-contained way? Your parent table doesn't work, regardless of the child tables - because it has 4 headings but no `<tr>` rows - and only two `<td>` elements. I think it would be a lot easier to help you if you created a cleaned-up [mre].

Comment: I created [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yh50nm4w/), which contains one DataTable containing 2 nested DataTables. Each table has different dimensions and is controlled by its own DataTables initialization code. It's my attempt to clean up the code in the question, making various assumptions along the way. Maybe it's what you need - or maybe it's not, but it may be of some help, anyway.

Comment: @andrewJames Yes, you are correct, I want to sort the columns of the child tables, just like in your example. I added dummy headers to each child table to give datatables the pieces it needs. Your fiddle also helped me recognize my struts logic is not correctly adding the `</tr>` tags after each pair of `<td>` columns. I'm expecting the iterator to create the table like `<tr><td>thing1</td><td>thing2</td></tr>` and so on but I'm getting extra `<tr>`'s which is causing the table to be malformed.

Comment: It sounds like you should ask a new, separate Struts question.

Comment: @andrewJames I will dig in on my own to solve that part, thanks :)

Comment: "_If my tables are malformed I can't tell_" - You can use an online HTML validator - for example, [https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html). Any decent code editor should also be able to do the same thing for you. Then, make sure your (now valid) `<table...</table>` HTML conforms to the [basic rules](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML) required by DataTables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so it's not hidden in a Fiddle in a comment, here is the same example I created, but as a Stack Snippet.

The snippet shows one parent DataTable containing 2 nested DataTables. Each of the three tables has different dimensions and is controlled by its own DataTables initialization code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#scrollTable').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    order: false // I disabled sorting for the parent table
  });

  $('#fillingTable').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false
  });

  $('#fullTable').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false
  });


});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div style="margin: 20px;">

      <table class="Dashboard" id="scrollTable">

        <caption>Cart Status</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Filling</th>
            <th>Full</th>
            <th>In Use</th>
            <th>Empty</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>

            <td>
              <table id="fillingTable" class="Data2">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Col 1</th>
                    <th>Col 2</th>
                    <th>Col 3</th>
                    <th>Col 4</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">W321DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">W543DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">W678DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">W405PC1</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">W221DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">W343DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">W278DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">W405PC1</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">X221DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">Z343DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">W278DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">Z405PC1</span></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>

            <td>
              <table id="fullTable" class="Data2">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Col 1</th>
                    <th>Col 2</th>
                    <th>Col 3</th>
                    <th>Col 4</th>
                    <th>Col 5</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">W321DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">W543DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">W678DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">W405PC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">W113DC1</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">W221DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">W343DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">W278DC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:red; font-weight: bold;">W405PC1</span></td>
                    <td><span style="color:green; font-weight: bold;">W813DC1</span></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>Whatever</td>
            <td>More whatever</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I used this as a sort of template to build my tables. I used the HTML validator you linked me to find the problems and that informed me on how to fix the problem(s). I had to account for an odd number of entries and add an empty `<td><span></span></td>` or `<td><a></a></td>` to the end so each row always has 2 columns as well as wrap all 4 tables in a `<tr>` for the parent table.

Comment: Nice - glad you figured it out!